# SimpleSamlphp redirect to wrong page

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I use simplesamlphp for SSO for my application. Let's say my website is "site A" and there is another site "site B" (not mine) that uses the same IDP (so the same credentials for login in).

When I connect to my site A, I am redirected to IDP, I login and I am redirected back to my site A, so everything is ok on the login. But then I try to connect to site B, I am connected to site B directly without entring any login/password (I guess because IDP is the same for both sites and use the same username/password). The problem is when I try to logout from my site A, I am not redirected to my logout page specified like this :

```
$auth = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$auth->logout('https://siteA/logoutpage.php');
```

I am redirected to site B showing 500 internal error and mentionning referer url is site A url.

Has anyone had this issue? I want to logout and  be redirected back to site A and not site B.
Thanks for your help

Comment: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/src/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php#L238 you can debug around this method here, to see what gets passed in, whether the URL sticks or not (maybe it's not allowed and falls back to default config)? Needs more debugging on your end. Also show the code of `logoutpage.php`, are you sure there's no further redirect there to siteB?